# Issue when implementing ReactDOM.createPortal (react 16 feature)

Tags: reactjs, dom, react-router, jsx, react-16

For the sake of clarification, let's say I have 3 components: `<Child>, <Parent>, <GrandParent>`

I am trying to render `<Child>` within `<GrandParent>`, without rendering `<Parent>` (from which `<Child>` is called).

**parent.js**

```
class Parent extends Component {
  ...
  componentDidMount() {
    return (
      <Route ... component={ Child } />
    );
  }

  render() {
  // the <Route> element is rendered here
  }
}
```

When clicking on the link within `<Parent>`, I want `<Parent>` to unmount and `<Child>` to render within `<GrandParent>`, which is what React new feature 'Portal' should achieve.

From the doc, this how it should be implemented:

```
ReactDOM.createPortal(componentToRender, elementToRenderInto);
// Hence in my case:
ReactDOM.createPortal(<Child />, document.getElementById('grand-parent'));
```

But I am not sure how/where to use this piece of code. Everything I tried rendered `<Child>` next to `<Parent>`, which is not what I want. Tips/doc/examples on the subject is very much welcomed

Comment: Can you share the entire code here. The code that is shared is a little ambiguous. createPortal only appends the componentToRender inside the elementToRenderInto. It does not remove any element. In your case i guess the Parent element is present inside the GrandParent element

Comment: Actually the code is more complex so I'm not sure it will improve readability to share everything. However, you are right, it lacks an important detail: the Parent is NOT present inside GrandParent.

Comment: it would be interesting to know the scenario, what are you trying to achieve eventually?

Answer (score 1):

If I get it right, grandparent component has to obtain a reference to underlying DOM node and pass it down to `parent`, then `parent` renders a portal with `child`.

I guess this could be what you are trying to achieve:

```
class GrandParent extends React.Component {
  state = {};
  getRef = that => this.setState({ self: that });
  render() {
    return (
      <div ref={this.getRef} style={{}}>
        +
        <Parent parent={this.state.self}>
          <Child />
        </Parent>
        +
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Parent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    if (this.props.parent)
      return createPortal(this.props.children, this.props.parent);
    return (
      <div>
        parent<Child />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>child</div>;
  }
}
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/yp985l069v)